# Should I change the bias during training with a neural net?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, bias-neuron

I mean, should I **adjust** the **bias** the way weights are?

Comment: The standard approach is to train them. So why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the bias is part of the trainable parameters and should change during training.